# (for playback from PC) Can I get EQ ability by adding an analogue mixer to PC & M-Audio M-Trrack 2x2 USB Audio Interface

Tags: mixer, audio-interfaces, analog, eq, pc

I am a total noob I just use this setup to listen to music.

I've got a PC which connects via USB to M-Audio M-Track 2X2 Audio Interface which then connects VIA 2 x Balanced TRS connectors/cables to my Sub and Studio Monitors.

Can I somehow add an Analogue Mixer so I can EQ the output basically?

I have googled but no one seems to want to do this, I am not recording anything or using any Mic's or Instruments. I simply want to hardware-EQ the output of the PC and Audio Interface like more bass/treble etc.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against using an external mixer for EQ in this case.  You have a professional quality audio interface with full DSP capability.  You can simply apply the desired EQ prior to output without needing to go through a mixer.  You will get higher quality and more feature rich EQs than you will be able to get with a cheap mixer.  You are literally just throwing money away if all you need is to EQ.

Answer (score -1):

A reply on another forum and music store sales advice, I have decided to go with a Graphic EQ (Behringer FBQ800 MINIFBQ Graphic EQ) instead of a Mixer (such as the Behringer XENYX Q502USB USB Mixer).

The reason I will get finer control.

Although the Q502USB would have replaced my M-Track saving space and money.

Comment: Using a mixer seems overkill for what you're after indeed. The difference on EQ is that a mixer would give you a number of bands of *parametric* EQ while the Behringer unit is a *graphic* EQ. The first is normally used to treat individual channels while the second is for stereo mixes and/or to 'tune' speakers.

Comment: Frankly, you could have had far finer-grained control doing it in software - something like [Voicemeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) ...donationware, so you could have donated 5 bucks or so & been richer too.

Comment: @Schizomorph Yes you have a point but I just wanted a bit more control than three channels, I ended up with 16 channels which is a bit too much, but it definitely helps with varying commercial mixes. Thanks.

Comment: @tetsujin Perhaps far finer and cheaper - but I wanted a hardware interface for the physical accessibility rather then switching windows - although one could go further and map those software functions to control devices if one had time. Thanks for the VB-Audio reference it looks fantastic.